How to destroy session by session attribute?
We are implementing SSO and it is materializing nicely in Yii 1.1.29. Yet, we need to log out from the Yii site if the user logs out from the IDP.
To make the scenario clearer, let's suppose that user foobar is having an active session both in the IDP (another site) and the SP (the Yii site). The Yii site has an access token of 'abcd', for example and the IDP is aware of this access token.
So, when the user logs out from the IDP, we would need to receive a request at the Yii site that would specify that the session whose access token is 'abcd' needs to be destroyed.
This would require us to

find the session by access token
destroy it

How can we find a session by one of its attributes and destroy it in Yii?
